# Characterization of nilpotency with normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

I have to prove the following:

Let G be a finite group then G is nilpotent $\iff$ every proper normal subgroup, $N\lhd G$, satisfy $[N,G]\leq N$

But it's not true that for every normal subgroup (even if G is not nilpotent) $[N,G]\subseteq N$ as $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}\in N$?

---

I found the solution in this [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/analytic-prop-groups/FC96FCA4B4EF667EC6F035513E11DB32). And as Maths Rahul pointed $N$ has to be a proper subgroup.

We prove it by induction over the order of $[N,G]$, if $[N,G]=1$ trivialy $[N,G]<N$.

If $[N,G]>1$ as $G$ is nilpotent we have $N\cap Z(G)\neq1$ for every normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ and $[N,G]\lhd G$ we have $[N,G]\cap Z(G)=K\neq1$. Taking the quotient
$$\frac{N}{K}\lhd\frac{G}{K}$$
by induction $$\frac{[N,G]}{K}<\frac{N}{K}$$
and using the correspondence $[N,G]<N$

Comment: What is true is that a finite group is nilpotent if and only if for every proper subgroup $H$, the normalizer of $H$ properly contains $H$.

Comment: I think, ($G$ is finite nilpotent if and only if $[N,G]$ is **proper** subgroup of $N$ for every normal subgroup $N$) would  be the correct one. The condition $[N,G]\leq N$ is equivalent to saying that $N$ is normal. So, your statement after if-and-only-if arrow puts nothing restriction about $N$.

Comment: @MathsRahul Thank you for your response. What changes if we add the hypothesis of $[N,G]$ being a proper subgroup?

Comment: This is mentioned in round-bracket statement of my comment. ($[N,G]$ is proper subgroup of $N$ for every normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ implies $G$ is nilpotent) as long as $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. Just consider any non-Abelian simple finite group, such as $A_5$. It does not have proper normal subgroups, so each of them satisfies your condition.

The fact that you mentioned: "For every normal subgroup $N$  $[N,G]\subseteq N$ as $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}\in N$" $(n\in N, g\in G)$" is true because $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}=n(gn^{-1}g^{-1})$ and $gn^{-1}g^{-1}$ is in $N$ since $N$ is normal.